# Xcode BoringSSL peer disconnect causing app to hang on startup

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, google-cloud-platform, boringssl

Recently I started getting inconsistent BoringSSL issues that is causing my cordova/ionic app to hang.  It happens about 1 out of every 4 or 5 times I launch the app from Xcode to a physically attached test iPhone 6.  The test phone uses WiFi only (no carrier network).  Having a devil of a time find any solid solutions or what the root of the problem is.

Some indicate its DNS, others say its related to Firebase...I have tried a few of the fixes those threads have mentioned but none are working for me.

```
[BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_input_finished(1543) [C3.1:2][0x12fd335c0] Peer disconnected during the middle of a handshake. Sending errSSLClosedNoNotify(-9816) alert
TIC TCP Conn Failed [3:0x2805712c0]: 3:-9816 Err(-9816)
[BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_input_finished(1543) [C5.1:2][0x12fe46470] Peer disconnected during the middle of a handshake. Sending errSSLClosedNoNotify(-9816) alert
TIC TCP Conn Failed [5:0x280575f80]: 3:-9816 Err(-9816)
[BoringSSL] boringssl_context_alert_callback_handler(3724) [C6.1:2][0x12fd43710] Alert level: fatal, description: inappropriate fallback
[BoringSSL] boringssl_session_errorlog(224) [C6.1:2][0x12fd43710] [boringssl_session_handshake_incomplete] SSL_ERROR_SSL(1): operation failed within the library
[BoringSSL] boringssl_session_handshake_error_print(205) [C6.1:2][0x12fd43710] 5097281768:error:1000043e:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_INAPPROPRIATE_FALLBACK:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl/boringssl-109.250.2/ssl/tls_record.cc:586:SSL alert number 86
[BoringSSL] boringssl_context_get_error_code(3617) [C6.1:2][0x12fd43710] SSL_AD_INAPPROPRIATE_FALLBACK
TIC TCP Conn Failed [6:0x280576640]: 3:-9860 Err(-9860)
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9860)
Task <02ADA890-35C5-4DE7-B0E5-6EC812CF79E6>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1200 [3:-9860])
Task <02ADA890-35C5-4DE7-B0E5-6EC812CF79E6>.<1> finished with error - code: -1200
nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x12fe15ea0] get output frames failed, state 8196
nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x12fe15ea0] get output frames failed, state 8196
```

If the app sees this error when initializing, the app hangs at the splash screen.  If it makes it past this issue then the app works just fine and I only see `nw_protocol_get_output_frames` messages every so often (don't know what those are about either).

Anyone have any ideas as to what is causing this, where to look or possibly what the fix is?

```
Cordova CLI: 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
cordova-ios: v5.0.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:  
Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.4
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.16
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.3
ios-deploy version: 1.9.4 
ios-sim version: 8.0.1 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v6.11.4
Xcode version: Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck at this error and what I did was enable all kinds of logs on XCode and that revealed that the error with this BoringSSL was from a call to the API Crashlytics of google. What solved this matter to me was enter on firebase, enable crashlytics for my project, install the plugin (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-crashlytics) and initialise it.

To find crashlytics on firebase you enter on the console and search on the left, under the menu quality, crashlytics. After that if you have already your GoogleService-Info.plist on your app, what remains is to install the plugin and initialise it according the docs.

[EDIT] Dont know if the above will contribute, because on another batch of tests I found that it didnt fix the issue. But when I add the next lines to config.plist it resolves:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>app-measurement.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>mtalk.google.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>play.googleapis.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>settings.crashlytics.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>googleapis.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>127.0.0.1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
```

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/42555
https://cocoacasts.com/app-transport-security-has-blocked-my-request

Comment: my issue has subsided alot, right around the time I fixed the [Fabric] issue which I then realized was related to Firebase Crashlytics.  However, I still get the error from time to time...previously it was like every 3rd or 4th time I compiled the app from Xcode to my physical test device.  Now it happens about once every 15 to 20 compiles.  I don't know if the new crash is related though.

Comment: Yes, exactly what was happening with me. After this "fix" I tested it 50 times without an error. Don't know if there is a better way, but did what I needed.

Comment: Hey, @rolinger, could you try what I suggest on my last edit? It would be nice to see if it solves your problem too.

Comment: I will after I get my current batch of iOS issues resolved.  My project is a Ionic v1 app, and I just upgraded the cli from v1.7.14 to v5.2.6 - everything works just fine on Android, but on iOS all sorts of problems.  The biggest one is `ionic cordova build iOS` simply just exits cleanly at `Preparing Firebase on iOS` - no issues or errors, but it fails to actually make the build, in fact the `platforms/ios/build` directory never gets created.

Comment: There were firebasex and ionic its that are now resolved.  going to get back to trying to figure out these boringssl issues - I enabled firebase crashlytics and fixed fabric issues, but still get the boringssl warnings.